# Problemas para descargar archivo csv con php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

Estoy intentando crear y descargar un archivo csv desde php, y no me funciona. Hice lo que siempre hago en estos casos, me fui a lo básico, y eliminé la consulta en base de datos y demás, para ir poco a poco y descubrir el problema. Entonces la primera prueba fue solo crear el csv en una ruta fija, lo cual si me funcionó. Al hacer los cambios para que me lo descargue en lugar de usar ruta fija, simplemente no lo hace y no tengo idea de cual será el problema.

El código que no funciona es:

```
<?php

$arreglo[0] = array("Nombre","Apellido","Animal","Fruto");
$arreglo[1] = array("Juan","Juarez","Jirafa","Jicama");
$arreglo[2] = array("Maria","Martinez","Mono","Mandarina");
$arreglo[3] = array("Esperanza","Escobedo","Elefante","Elote");
$filename ="prueba.csv";
$delimitador = ",";
$encapsulador = '"';

//asigno el header para descargar el archivo en lugar de escribirlo
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

error_log("se supone que estoy en eso");
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
foreach ($arreglo as $linea) {
    fputcsv($f, $linea, $delimitador, $encapsulador);
 }
  rewind($f);
  fclose($f);

?>
```

El código que si funciona es:

```
  <?php

$arreglo[0] = array("Nombre","Apellido","Animal","Fruto");
$arreglo[1] = array("Juan","Juarez","Jirafa","Jicama");
$arreglo[2] = array("Maria","Martinez","Mono","Mandarina");
$arreglo[3] = array("Esperanza","Escobedo","Elefante","Elote");
$ruta ="prueba.csv";
$delimitador = ",";
$encapsulador = '"';

error_log("se supone que estoy en eso");
$f = fopen($ruta, 'w');
foreach ($arreglo as $linea) {
    fputcsv($f, $linea, $delimitador, $encapsulador);
 }
  rewind($f);
  fclose($f);

?>
```

=== ACTUALIZACIÓN
Encontré que el problema está relacionado con la forma en que ejecuto este php, que lo llamo desde otro archivo usando jQuery y ajax. Entonces encontré que puedo descargar un archivo desde jQuery usando el url.
Modifiqué todo para que creara el archivo en el servidor, en la misma ubicación donde se encuentra el php, y retorne el url, desde jQuery hago la descarga.

Ahora el problema es que funcionó muy bien en mi servidor local, con XAMPP, pero cuando lo subo al servidor real, genera el archivo pero no lo baja. Si alguien puede ayudarme con esto lo agradecería mucho.

El php finalmente quedó así:

```
<?php
include('Db.php');
include('miembro_function.php');
/*require_once("./PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
require_once("./PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
require_once("./PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");*/

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
      session_start();

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
      session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['type'])) or (($_SESSION['type'] <> "A") and ($_SESSION['type'] <> "U") and ($_SESSION['type'] <> "C"))) 
      header("Location: ./index.php");

//asigno datos importantes
$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "miembros.csv";


//creo un apuntador al archivo
$f = fopen($filename, 'w');

//asigno el encabezado
$fields = array(utf8_decode('Número Colegiado'), 'Tipo Documento', utf8_decode('Número Documento'), 'Nombre', 'Apellido 1', 'Apellido 2', 'Fecha Nacimiento', 'Nacionalidad', 'Sexo', 'Especialidad','Fecha Inicio','Motivo Alta','Origen','Fecha Fin','Motivo Baja','eMail');
$escribe = fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

// tomo los datos de la base de datos
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM miembros WHERE Colegio = '"  . $_POST["colegio"] . "'");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
//escribo cada línea
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $lineData = array(utf8_decode($row[2]), utf8_decode($row[3]), utf8_decode($row[4]), utf8_decode($row[5]), utf8_decode($row[6]), utf8_decode($row[7]), utf8_decode($row[8]), utf8_decode($row[9]), utf8_decode($row[10]), utf8_decode($row[11]), utf8_decode($row[12]), utf8_decode($row[13]), utf8_decode($row[14]), utf8_decode($row[15]), utf8_decode($row[16]), utf8_decode($row[17] ));
    $escribe = fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    
}

 fclose($f);

 $enlace_actual = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    echo substr($enlace_actual, 0, strlen($enlace_actual) - 16) . $filename;
?>
```

Y la llamada la ejecuto así:

```
$("#exportar_button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"exportar_csv.php",
                method:'POST',
                data:{colegio:Colegio[cParam]},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = data;
                    let hoy = new Date();
                    fileName = "miembros_" + Colegio[cParam] + "_" + String(hoy.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(hoy.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + hoy.getFullYear() + ".csv";
                    a.download = fileName;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    a.remove();
                },              
            });
    });
```

Comment: Pero la `$ruta`...¿Cuál es? ¿No indicas la carpeta?

Comment: al no poner carpeta lo escribe en la misma ubicación que el archivo php, eso si funciona bien, lo que no funciona bien es cuando trato de descargarlo en lugar de escribirlo ahí, que es el primer código

Comment: Es decir... inicias la ejecución sin archivo .csv, y después de ejecutarlo sí te lo ha creado. ¿Quieres decir eso?

Comment: Si, y si existe lo sobreescribe

Answer (score 0):

María del Pilar, la clave está en `fopen('php://memory', 'w');`, que debería ser `fopen('php://output', 'w');`.
Y también, que dado la salida es el output, no debes usar el `rewind($f)`. Prueba así, y debería funcionarte sin problemas

```
<?php

    $arreglo[0] = array("Nombre","Apellido","Animal","Fruto");
    $arreglo[1] = array("Juan","Juarez","Jirafa","Jicama");
    $arreglo[2] = array("Maria","Martinez","Mono","Mandarina");
    $arreglo[3] = array("Esperanza","Escobedo","Elefante","Elote");
    $filename ="prueba.csv";
    $delimitador = ",";
    $encapsulador = '"';

    //asigno el header para descargar el archivo en lugar de escribirlo
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset:UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //error_log("se supone que estoy en eso");
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($arreglo as $linea) {
        fputcsv($f, $linea, $delimitador, $encapsulador);
    }
    //rewind($f);
    fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: La verdad es que te había hecho la pregunta confundiendo qué código te funcionaba y cuál no, porque pensé que era al revés. Pero esta respuesta ya es al que no te iba bien

Comment: si, pero eso ya lo probé y tampoco funciona, creo que el problema puede ir por el tema de utf-8, quizá algún tema de configuración de php, porque haciendo otras pruebas de otras cosas me encuentro con que no me lee bien los acentos y ñ

Comment: el tema es complicado, ni siquiera me hace un simple printf o echo, comenté todo y solo puse eso y no escribe en pantalla, por ahí debe ser el problema

Comment: Y ese es el único contenido del archivo php? ¿Quiero decir... es un archivo PHP limpio (con sólo este código) el que estás probando? Lo comento para que no haya etiquetas o elementos de otro tipo (`<html>`, otros headers, etc.)

Comment: Y por cierto... el `error_log("se supone que estoy en eso");` lo tienes comentado, ¿no?

Comment: no, de hecho ese archivo se llama desde otro con html y demás, pero es bastante grande. El error_log no está comentado, pero lo tengo en otros archivos php y no es un problema, ese escribe en el log de php